# Macbook Pro 13" Mid 2010 bluetooth headset

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, headphones

I have a "KINIVO BTH220" wireless bluetooth headset. I can connect it without any problem with iPhone 4S. 
However, when I try to connect it with MacbookPro 13" (Mid 2010), it won't show up in the browse device list.

Is there any fix for that? or Is it MacbookPro 13" doesn't support wireless bluetooth audio profile?

Can someone please put light on this?

Comment: I would say that it can not be connected to 2 devices at same time!

Comment: I am not connecting it with 2 devices at same time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if your BT is paired/connected with the iPhone it can not be paired/connected with Mac, so disable the iPhone connection.